# How can I tell which apps will "work" inside my desktop environment (Gnome 3)?

Tags: opensuse, gnome3

OpenSuse 13.1

I have an embarrassingly simple question that I'm compelled to ask: How can I tell which apps will "work" inside my desktop environment (Gnome 3)?  Do certain apps require KDE?  What should I look out for that would tell me?

For example, I'm curious about Linux video game emulator programs and noticed a list here: http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20081012160727880/VideoConsoles.html  It's unclear to me which of these require Gnome, which require KDE, and which of these don't work at all inside desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to look for the program's dependencies?

I don't use OpenSUSE but on Xubuntu (Debian-based), I can look at what dependencies a program requires *before* I install that program. For that, I use `apt-cache show program_name`.

In the following examples, I replaced `program_name` with `xmahjongg`, `gnome-mahjongg` and `kmahjongg`. The dependencies are shown below:

```
xmahjongg
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libx11-6

gnome-mahjongg
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.4.0), librsvg2-2 (>= 2.32.0), dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend

kmahjongg
Depends: kde-runtime, libc6 (>= 2.14), libkdecore5 (>= 4:4.11.2), libkdegames6 (>= 4:4.10.80), libkdeui5 (>= 4:4.11.2), libkio5 (>= 4:4.11.2), libkmahjongglib4 (>= 4:4.9.80), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.1), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), kdegames-mahjongg-data (>= 4:4.10)
```

By inspecting the output, I can tell that `gnome-mahjongg` is (obviously) a GNOME program because it requires `libgtk-3-0` and that `kmahjongg` will pull in `kde` and `qt` dependencies.

For software which isn't in my Operating System's software center, I'd need to consult the homepage or website for the respective software. Requirements probably are specified there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on GNOME 3.12 or above, there's actually an option built-in to GNOME Software for some package managers. When you look at a piece of software, it will have a star rating. This star rating tells you how well the application will integrate with GNOME. The higher, the better - if it's supported and you're on the proper version of GNOME, use this to inform your package installation decisions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Almost all of this

As any *GNU/Linux* distribution is *open-source*, you must be able to install a *C Compiler* in your host, with all needed libraries.

The command `ldd` may list wich installed libraries is used by any binary:

```
ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff25dff000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5dea4ae000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5dea2a6000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f5dea09c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5de9d11000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5de9b0d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5dea6ed000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5de98f0000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f5de96eb000)
```

Many *project website* hold a history and some pre-compiled binaries suitable for specific version of most common distributions.

#### Gnome + KDE cohabitation

In many configuration, having *KDE* application running under *Gnome* environment don't break anything, same in reverse order: having *Gnome* application that run under *KDE* desktop could work without real problem.

#### Distribution dependancies

Each distribution come with his *package manager*. This tool is responsible of maintaining right required libraries with all installed stuff.

This could be assimiled as a *time tag* where

> At **specific** date, **this** stuff was run under **this** `kernel` version **and this** `x-server` version **and this** version of `libc` **and ...**  so on.

Installing required stuff to run **C compiler** must be - and is, in fact, generaly well - documented in distribution's docs.